# Problem creating ActiveMQ Artemis broker instance on Raspberry pi 3B+

Tags: java, iot, activemq-artemis

I want to install ActiveMQ Artemis on my Raspberry pi 3B+, but I am getting a Java related error. I am using Java version 8.
I have followed the total procedure as [explained here](https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-activemq-artemis-on-ubuntu-18-04-76bb4975308b).

While attempting to start the broker instance using command
`$ sudo /var/lib/test-broker/bin/artemis run`
I am getting the following error:

```
OpenJDK Client VM warning: G1 GC is disabled in this release.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

I have tried to increase the heap space but it didn't work. Any help to remove this error would be appreciated.

Comment: That thingy only has 1GB LPDDR2 SDRAM... and such issues have no relation to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ActiveMQ Artemis server uses the G1 collector(-XX:+UseG1GC), 512MB for the initial size of the memory allocation pool(-Xms512M) and 2GB for the maximum size of the memory allocation pool(-Xmx2G). If your computer has less memory, or you want to run it with more available RAM, modify the values in `artemis.profile` file accordingly otherwise remove the hardcoded values.

Comment: Thank you @Domenico. This solution has solved my problem.